# Default value for empty integer fields when importing CSV data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I'm importing a CSV into a MySQL table with `LOAD DATA INFILE`. One of the table's fields stores zip code data, which I've defined in the table structure `contributor_zipcode INT`.

In the CSV, this field is sometimes empty. When I execute the `LOAD` query, MySQL will throw a warning like:

`Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'contributor_zipcode' at row 180`

I've tried redefining the field as `contributor_zipcode INT DEFAULT '0'`, which creates the same warning, and `contributor_zipcode INT DEFAULT NULL`, which MySQL won't allow. Any advice?

Comment: can you post a dummy line from your CSV file?

Comment: `2004,urn:fec:transaction,indiv:2004:1902928,15,24020610238,f,1000.00,2004-06-15,"FELDSTEIN, MARTIN",h30013132661,I,HARVARD UNIVERSITY,,M,,BELMONT,MA,02478,H5100,Harvard University,,,,Lisa Murkowski (R),N00026050,R,P,AK,AK,,Lisa Murkowski - US Senate,C00384529,R,f,,,federal:senate,federal:senate,I,W`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The empty values are being interpreted as the empty string (''), not NULL, so the default value is not being used.

If you want to explicitly control the handling of these empty strings, the best thing to do is to load them into a user variable, and then set the column conditionally using the user variable.

You could use this to set the value to whatever you want (NULL, 0, etc.).

Here's an example, assuming you want to set it to 0:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '...'
INTO TABLE your_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(column_one,..., @contributor_zipcode,..., column_n)
SET contributor_zipcode = IF(@contributor_zipcode='',0,@contributor_zipcode);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. One follow-up: will MySQL allow me to set the value of an INT field to NULL? Or would you recommend just using 0?

Comment: Yes, you can set an INT to NULL, which is probably what you want to do in this case. You just need to make sure the column is defined to allow NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

In Csv I replaced all the "" with "\N" before I run the script, this creates a null field in db

Answer (score 0):

For some elements (e.g. zip codes), may be better for default value to be `null`, not `0`.

Assume you have a table of people called (what else) `People`.

```
create table People (
    id int,
    first_name varchar(30),
    last_name varchar(50),
    city varchar(50),
    state varchar(50),
    zip int
);
```

Next, load your `file.csv` into the `People` table.  *Note the last line (starting with `set`) where `zip` is assigned `null` if the value in the file is `""` (aka an empty string)*

```
load data local infile '/path/to/file.csv'
into table People
fields 
    terminated by ','
    enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(id, first_name, last_name, city, state, @zip)
set zip = if(@zip='', null, @zip);
```