# MySQL for Python: Incorrect Integer value

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have the same question as asked here:

[Default value for empty integer fields when importing CSV data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394228/default-value-for-empty-integer-fields-when-importing-csv-data-in-mysql)

I keep getting the warning "Incorrect Integer value" when importing a csv file into Mysql. I've read all the relevant questions/answers here, and the link above is my direct question.  But I'm trying to implement the answer given there in Python 2.7, and I can't seem to get it working.

My code below is my attempt to implement the answer from the above post.  I think the issue is the syntax for using the "Set" clause in my Load DATA Local Infile statement...I would really appreciate any help since MySQL automatically converts empty INT's to "0" and that would mess up my analysis since I want blanks to be null. My code is:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(blah, blah, blah)
cursor = db.cursor()

sql = """CREATE TABLE PLAYER(
       PLAYER_ID INT,
       DATE DATETIME,
       BATTING_AVERAGE INT
       )"""

cursor.execute(sql)
statement = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/file.csv'
INTO TABLE PLAYER
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
SET BATTING_AVERAGE = IF(@BATTING_AVERAGE='',NULL,@BATTING_AVERAGE)
IGNORE 1 LINES;"""
```

The error that this code gives is:

ProgramingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right synatx to use near 'IGNORE 1 Lines at line 5")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SET` and `IGNORE` clauses are backwards.  Try swapping them:

```
statement = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path/file.csv'
INTO TABLE PLAYER
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES
SET BATTING_AVERAGE = IF(@BATTING_AVERAGE='',NULL,@BATTING_AVERAGE);"""
```

Comment: `COLUMNS TERMINATED BY` for some reason looks wrong to me. I wonder if that should be `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`

Comment: @JonClements Both are correct syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Although I simplified my code for this example, I have a few other columns in the table that have this same issue. When I try putting a line below the last line in 'statement' that sets a different column name, I get the same error I was getting about a ProgrammingError.  If it's not too much trouble, could you add another Set clause to your code if there is another column that should have null instead of 0?  Thanks so much!

Comment: @user7186 You can; delimit them with commas.  `SET column_a = 1, column_b = 2, ...`

Comment: @cdhowie,*I ran into another error and just wanted to add it here so that others don't see this code and have the same problem.  Turns out that this makes every value of BATTING_AVERAGE become null, even when values are actually given and it is not blank.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: @user7186 Maybe because of the `@` prefix, which references a variable instead of a column?  Presumably that variable has never been initialized.  Try removing the `@` characters.