# Setting blank fields to NULL when importing CSV in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I'm losing my mind. I've tried the verified answer provided here: [Default value for empty integer fields when importing CSV data in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394228/default-value-for-empty-integer-fields-when-importing-csv-data-in-mysql)

Here is the screenshot of my version of the [SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufxOM.png) that I'm trying to do. But I keep getting the same error and I don't know the reason why. I based my query on the link I provided above. Please help me. All responses are highly appreciated.

[image]I've already created the table, here is the `describe` of the table.

[image] This is the test query.
[image] This is the test data.

It doesn't also work for this one.

Comment: most probably your table field doesnt allow nulls, show us your `create table`? also show us what query are you using. My suggestion, try to create a basic sample with few fields and start adding things from there when you make it work.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've edited it and provided the 'describe' of the table that I created. Sorry for bad english

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza any idea on how to fix this? Please help.

Comment: I told you try to create a smaller sample, very few field and make it work, then start adding fields. Only seeing your query cant see the problem

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've tried it and the same goes for the test data using the same query. Check the edit that I've made. Thank you so much for responding.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I also tried replacing the blank with "\N" but I also get the same error saying the value is incorrect for those particular fields

Comment: Anyone please help.

Comment: sorry I dont have mysql to test it. My suggestion try to find a tutorial first. And try ot import a file without nulls, Once you have the import working try to include the nulls

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've tried inputting the test data without nulls and it works just fine. The problem is that my actual data is so big that I can't edit it because it takes up too much of my time. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Again create a small file and start testing

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've said it a lot of times. What I want is to enter the data that contains null values but it doesn't work even though I'm using my test data.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza It works now. Changed 'load data infile' to 'load data local infile'. Thank you so much.